# Rails creating user groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a bit new to rails and I want to create user groups in my application. A user can belong to many groups and a group can have many users in it. For instance there would be a first grade group with all first grade teachers in it and they will also belong to a number of other groups.

This is my current code.

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
end
```

At the moment if I assign a user to a group in the Ruby console it only allows one group id. How can I make a user have multiple group_ids?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: @AbM I did see this however I was confused because I only have two models?

Comment: You need to create a third model, such as `Membership` that has a `user_id` and a `group_id`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that case, you should have a NxN (many to many) relationship. So you'll need an additional model for that. You can generate it like this:

```
rails g model UserGroup user:references group:references
```

Then, you change your models like this:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :users, through: :user_groups
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :groups, through: :user_groups
end
```

That way, you can access a User groups like this:

```
User.first.groups
```

or a Group users like this:

```
Group.first.users
```

Hope this helps... good luck!

Comment: How could I get an array of ALL users in the group as well as the number of users in the group?

Comment: @TrentonTyler yeah. If you access an group instance (like in the example) Group.first.users, you'll get all the users for that group. If you do Group.first.users.count, you'll get the number of users for that group